# Use of uninitialized value $" in join or string. How can I use left join without this?

Tags: sqlite, join, left-join, inner-join

I am using a SQLite log parser for some Apache logs of the form:

```
X.Y.Z.W - userID1 [01/Jan/2014:06:31:22 -0400] "GET /url1 HTTP/1.1" 200 11366400 "redirecturl1" "user agent1"
X2.Y2.Z2.W2 - userID1 [01/Jan/2014:07:31:22 -0400] "GET /url2 HTTP/1.1" 200 11366400 "redirecturl2" "user agent2"
Etc...
```

I want to do a couple of comparisons with these logs, so I create an auxiliary table (urlcompare) to compare them to:

```
CREATE TABLE urlcompare (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Request TEXT NOT NULL, RequestName TEXT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO urlcompare VALUES (null, '/url1', 'TOTAL');
INSERT INTO urlcompare VALUES (null, '/url2', 'TOTAL');
INSERT INTO urlcompare VALUES (null, '/url3', 'TOTAL');
INSERT INTO urlcompare VALUES (null, '/url4', 'TOTAL');
INSERT INTO urlcompare VALUES (null, '/url5', 'TOTAL');
INSERT INTO urlcompare VALUES (null, '/url6', 'TOTAL');
INSERT INTO urlcompare VALUES (null, '/url7', 'TOTAL');
INSERT INTO urlcompare VALUES (null, '/url8', 'TOTAL');
```

On the SQLite script I load my log file:

```
load logfile
```

Then I try selecting urls from the logs that match the urls in urlcompare, (the table "logs" contains the parsing of the log file in SQLite form):

```
SELECT user, MIN(datetime(Date, 'utc')) AS Mintime FROM urlcompare LEFT JOIN logs ON urlcompare.Request=logs.Request GROUP BY user ORDER BY urlcompare.id ASC;
```

I get the results and the error:

```
Use of uninitialized value $" in join or string at /usr/bin/asql line 593.
```

**Note: If I substitute the Left Join by Inner Join I get the same results without the error/warning.** However, I have some areas where I need to compare the log files to urls in a table (table A) and show all the urls in table A with their "hits" in the log file (ie. I need to show urls with 0 hits). Hence my need for "table A LEFT JOIN logs", in these cases, how can I solve the problem without getting this error?

Comment: ASQL: Query Apache logfiles via SQLite

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand the problem, when I am left joining in the form

```
FROM tableA LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.attributeC = TableB.attributeC
```

The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all rows from the left table (tableA), with the matching rows in the right table (tableB). **The result is NULL in the right side when there is no match.**

So when I try retrieving arguments from tableB with no match I get a "null"...